# Getting Error in elastic search while run using angular 6

Tags: angular, elasticsearch, compiler-errors

I am using `angular 6` while installing `elasticsearch` getting this below error...

[image]

I am using `elasticsearch : 15.0.0` version

I had installed elastic search using `npm i elasticsearch --save` command